# Do Rails turbolinks work in Phantomjs and if not, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, turbolinks

I've just tried to test a bit of JS that's supposed to fire on page load after a turbolink is clicked. Although I have verified it works in Chrome, Phantomjs doesn't seem to work and appears to be using normal links. I saw that some browsers don't support the HTML5 history API properly yet, but surely Phantomjs, being based on Webkit, should not be one of them?

Comment: Here is an old issue in the system regarding [it](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/pull/86). Does that still apply?

Comment: @creativereason: Took me a minute to find the link in your comment :)

Comment: Sorry, should have linked a longer amount of the text than it :)

Comment: There seems to be an older version of webkit in use that does not yet support the history api fully. 2.0 might do. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11100